# Проблема с инфоблоками Bitrix в Openserver

Tags: битрикс, openserver

Установил Bitrix на Openserver и возникла такя проблема с инфоблоками. Они как будто не до конца прогружаются.[image: Здесь должны быть таблицы а не сырой текст html]

Answer (score 0):

Протестируйте конфигурацию на совместимость и наличие всех необходимых расширений PHP и настроек самого PHP.
С вероятностью 100%, тест покажет несовместимость.
Я сам с подобным столкнулся, оказалось что надо очень постараться, что бы Битрикс поехал на OpenServer... Я его настроить не смог и в результате развернул Виртуальную машину с окружением под Битрикс.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том что конфиг Apache по умолчанию игнорирует пути с точками, поэтому некоторые скрипты, стили и файлы не подключаются.
В конфиге Apache необходимо закомментировать строки:

```
<LocationMatch "/\.(?!well-known)">
Require all denied
</LocationMatch>
```