# Как изменить конфигурацию Apache для Open Server Panel

Tags: битрикс, openserver

Я перешел по пути C:\OSPanel\modules\http\Apache_2.4-PHP_7.2-7.4\conf и открыл папку  httpd.conf. Там мне необходимо закомментировать код ниже (из за неправильной работы админ панели bitrix [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1318182/Проблема-с-инфоблоками-bitrix-в-openserver](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1318182/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-bitrix-%D0%B2-openserver) ):

```
<LocationMatch "/\.(?!well-known)">
Require all denied
</LocationMatch>
```

Я закомментировал и после перезапуска сервера в файл изменился и код представленый выше раскомментировался. Скажите как мне правильно отредактировать httpd.conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо править конфигурацию в директории C:\OSPanel\userdata\config.
В вашем случае в файлах

Apache_2.4-PHP_7.2-7.4+Nginx_1.23_vhostn.conf
Apache_2.4-PHP_7.2-7.4_server.conf

Конфиги которые в папке modules генерируются автоматически при запуске сервера.

Answer (score 0):

Можно закомментировать старое правило и добавить новое

```
<LocationMatch "/\.(?!well-known)">
    # Require all denied
      Require all granted
</LocationMatch>
```

в версии OpenServer 5.4.1, файл кофигурации Apache_2.4-PHP_7.2-7.4_server.conf