# Перенос сайта с opencart 3 на openserver

Tags: php, opencart, opencart3.x

3 дня мучаюсь над переносом сайта на локальный хостинг. Вопрос у меня будет несколько, надеюсь кто поможет, подскажет.
Мне дали рабочие файлы сайта с хостинга (админ файлы opencart 3 и .базу данных).
Задача такая, мне нужно, чтобы я мог локально вносить изменения на сайт.
Пришел к такому выводу, что необходимо сделать точно такую же середу как и на живом хостинге.
Перенес раб файлы на опенсерв, создал базу данных, загрузил через консоль (так как файл большей).

- Дальше, есть основной файл config.php - я его отключил от index.php и создал config-local.php (чтобы локально все файлы были подключены) - не знаю, правильно ли это. В admin папке я ничего не менял.
- Дальше, у меня просто опенсервер открывает мой сайт без отображения стилей. Только html разметка отображается. А по инструкции должна запускаться установка opencart. Также прописывал в строке после имени хостинга/install/index.php (кажется так)  и всё равно загрузка не начинается.
- У меня еще куча вопросов, но хотя бы с этого начать и разобраться что я не так делаю.

Может в config не правильно прописал?

```html
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://brille-local/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://brille-local/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', 'D:/Programs/OSPanel/domains/brille-local/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', 'D:/Programs/OSPanel/domains/brille-local/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', 'D:/Programs/OSPanel/domains/brille-local/image/');
define('DIR_STORAGE', 'D:/Programs/OSPanel/domains/brille-local/system/storage/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', DIR_APPLICATION . 'view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', DIR_SYSTEM . 'config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', DIR_STORAGE . 'cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', DIR_STORAGE . 'logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', DIR_STORAGE . 'modification/');
define('DIR_SESSION', DIR_STORAGE . 'session/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', DIR_STORAGE . 'upload/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', HTTPS_SERVER);

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'brille-local');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'brille_brille');
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как было
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не поленитесь, хотя бы откройте devtools на локальном сайте и посмотрите, что за ошибку вы получаете. Скорее всего потому что пытаетесь загрузить файлы через https, когда локально есть только http (настройкой сертификатов вы вряд ли занимались, openserver по умолчанию ничего с этим не делает)

Comment: В девтулсе куча ошибок. Главная я так понимаю связана с opencart.css, но разве если я её исправлю, загрузка может начаться? (ошибка мне ничего не говорит). Я не до конца понимаю коду смотреть, так как впервые разбираюсь с этим. А в руководстве ответом нет.

Comment: Может мы бы могли перейти в телеграм, для более быстро общения. Я буду вам признателен, если вы мне поможете, подскажете.

Comment: Если честно я не совсем понимаю, почему картинки, стили, библиотеки и т д не работаю ( ошибки показывает). Я кроме паки config-local ничего не менял.

Comment: Также, я сейчас закомментировал https строку и половина ошибок исчезла, но появилась https  ошибка. добавил фото

Comment: ткните в любой файл, отдающий 404 ошибку, и посмотрите по какому пути сервер пытается найти этот файл, дальше разберетесь

Comment: не понял вас. 
увидел, что скаченный файлы с веб=хостинга был без папки install и image
но после этого, всё равно ошибки не уходят. я так понимаю вопрос всё же с подключениями путей.
немойно что делать с последним: define('DIR_STORAGE', 'D:/Programs/OSPanel/domains/brille-local/system/storage/');
по идее он должен быть без system. но такого пути нет. а почему в веб-хостинге работает? 
storage - папок и файло несоколько, но они все вложенные. и как мне понять какой правильный?

Comment: Может это поможет
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1510983/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-apache-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-open-server-panel